# What happens to argument value of first .next() in generator function*

Tags: javascript, generator

Consider this generator function.

Why is the argument of the first call to `.next()` essentially lost? It will yield and log each of the letter strings but skips `"A"`. Can someone offer an explanation. Please advise on a way that I can access each argument each argument of the `.next()` method and store it in an array within the generator function?

```js
function* gen(arg) {
  let argumentsPassedIn = [];
  while (true) {
    console.log(argumentsPassedIn);
    arg = yield arg;
    argumentsPassedIn.push(arg);
  }

}


const g = gen();
g.next("A"); // ??
g.next("B");
g.next("C");
g.next("D");
g.next("E");
```

Comment: From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*#passing_arguments_into_generators): "the first call of next executes from the start of the function until the first yield statement"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*#passing_arguments_into_generators)

> The first call of next executes from the start of the function until the first yield statement

So when you call the first `next`, it just calls the generator function from start to till the `first yield` and then returns and from `next` call it works normal.

To make you code work, you should try like this.

```js
function* gen(arg) {
  let argumentsPassedIn = [];
  while (true) {
    console.log(argumentsPassedIn);
    arg = yield arg;
    argumentsPassedIn.push(arg);
  }

}


const g = gen();
g.next()
g.next("A"); // ??
g.next("B");
g.next("C");
g.next("D");
g.next("E");
```

Comment: Not quite. `arg` will be "A" in that first call. `argumentsPassedIn` will be empty (since it is declared as an empty array), logged as empty, then "A" will be yielded and the function completes (without pushing).

Comment: Yeah, bit confusing.

Comment: If so, the question is, Why isn't there an empty `arg` in the array?

Comment: Why would there be? As I said, nothing was pushed. From the very sentence you quote: "executes from the start of the function **until the first yield statement**". The `push` is after the first yield statement, so it never gets called. The interesting question to me is, why is *anything* pushed. You would think it would just keep yielding the passed in value and never run the `push`.

Comment: Ah make sense, the first one calls till the yield. I quoted but just now understood  clearly 

Answer (score 3):

This is a limitation of generator functions. If you really want to be able to use the first argument, you can construct your own iterator manually.

```js
const gen = () => {
  const argumentsPassedIn = [];
  const makeObj = () => ({
    done: false,
    value: undefined,
    next: (arg) => {
      argumentsPassedIn.push(arg);
      console.log(argumentsPassedIn);
      return makeObj();
    },
  });
  return makeObj();
}


const g = gen();
g.next("A");
g.next("B");
g.next("C");
g.next("D");
g.next("E");
```

Comment: This seems like it would be better posted on the duplicate...

Answer (score 1):

The parameter passed to the first call to `.next()` is ignored as of ES2022. This is because the first call to `.next()` runs the function until the **first** `yield` or `return` is encountered and the following calls will make `yield` operator return the value passed as a parameter. This is usually solved by calling `.next()` unconditionally after calling the generator function.

There is, however, a [stage 2 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-function.sent) that aims to solve this problem by introducing new syntax to get the value passed to the `.next()` method that most recently resumed execution of the generator.